# DataFrame check if nested json column exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have some Jsons as follow

```
{"Location":
  {"filter":
      {"name": "houston", "Disaster": "hurricane"},
  }
}
{"Location":
  {"filter":
      {"name": "florida", "Disaster": "hurricane"},
  }
}
{"Location":
  {"filter":
      {"name": "seattle"},
  }
}
```

After I use **spark.read.json("myfile.json")** I want to filter out the data rows that do not contains a disaster. In my example the seattle row should be filtered out.

I tried

```
val newTable = df.filter($"Location.filter.Disaster" isnotnull)
```

but that gives me struct Disaster does not exist error.

So how do I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `json` data seems to be corrupted, i.e. it **cannot** be read into **valid dataframe** by using `spark.read.json("myfile.json")`

There is a workaround for this by using `wholeTextFiles` api

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("myfile.json")
val json = rdd.flatMap(_._2.replace(":\n", ":").replace(",\n", "").replace("}\n", "}").replace(" ", "").replace("}{", "}\n{").split("\n"))
```

This should give you `rdd` data (**valid jsons**) as

```
{"Location":{"filter":{"name":"houston","Disaster":"hurricane"}}}
{"Location":{"filter":{"name":"florida","Disaster":"hurricane"}}}
{"Location":{"filter":{"name":"seattle"}}}
```

Now you can read the `json rdd` into `dataframe`

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(json)
```

which should give you

```
+---------------------+
|Location             |
+---------------------+
|[[hurricane,houston]]|
|[[hurricane,florida]]|
|[[null,seattle]]     |
+---------------------+
```

with `schema` as

```
root
 |-- Location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- filter: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Disaster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Now that you have a *valid dataframe*, you can apply the `filter` you were applying

```
val newTable = df.filter($"Location.filter.Disaster" isnotnull)
```

`newTable` would be

```
+---------------------+
|Location             |
+---------------------+
|[[hurricane,houston]]|
|[[hurricane,florida]]|
+---------------------+
```